# Is xamarin.iOS supports communication notification?

Tags: ios, xamarin, push-notification, communication

We are using communication notification to update notification icon, but for us it's not working for xamarin project.

var intent = new INSendMessageIntent(null,INOutgoingMessageType.Text,
"Message content",
null,
"unique-conversation-id-1",
null,
sender,null);

```
    // Use the intent to initialize the interaction.
    var interaction = new INInteraction(intent: intent, response: null);

    interaction.Direction = INInteractionDirection.Incoming;

    interaction.DonateInteraction((error) =>
    {
        // ...
    });

    NSError error1 = null;
    var content = request.Content;
    var updatedContent = content.Update(intent, out error1);

    contentHandler(updatedContent);
```

Comment: Did you enable the Communication Notifications capability in your app target before you implement communication notifications ?

Comment: Yes, added entry in entitlement.plist. 
<key>Communication Notifications</key>
 <true/>